# how to read arabic in json object

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

i am using extjs as front end tool my requirement is to show the arabic data from application properties to json grid in extjs.but the problem is it is showing only question marks any help would be appreciable Thanks.

Comment: That should work with UTF-8. Are your content types / charsets specified correctly? And your browser also needs to have the appropriate fonts. Can you open other Arabic content from the web?

Comment: This question has too little detail to be answerable. The encoding is screwing up *somewhere*. That could be anywhere, depending on what exactly you're doing. Give us more information, preferably after you have debugged yourself where exactly your characters go awry.

Comment: How the json is coming? Are you embedding to the HTML file or loading it dynamically by Ajax? You may not be calling Ajax, but you might be passing URL. Is that so? It's better you show your full code

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the encoding meta tag in the HEAD to utf8

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html